# Craft is unable to determine if an update is available at this time

Tags: error, updates

No chance to update on my local machine and on my live site.
On the staging site it works but that's the same server as the live site.

I've cleared the caches and checked the logs.

Local there is only this error:

```
2016/06/19 19:41:01 [error] [application] Error in Craft\Et::phoneHome. Message: Cannot overwrite an existing license.key file.
```

But I run the site in DEV Mode.

Any ideas? I'm a bit unhappy about it :/

Best
David

Comment: Looks like Craft doesn't have write permission, which is usually caused by incorrect permissions... How are you running the server locally? Vagrant? MAMP?

Comment: With MAMP. You mean this is a Mamp Setting? But why it works on my staging server and not on live? They run on the Same Hoster.

Comment: Have you tried removing the key? You don't need it in dev mode but I'm guessing the permissions problem is what's causing the issue on LIVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error message because there is an existing `craft/config/license.key` file in place for your local installation and there is no record of that install on the Craft/web service end.  Likely you've just copied an existing `license.key` file from another site into this new installation.

So the web service on the Craft end thinks that since it's a new Craft client installation it needs to send down a new `license.key` file for you to start using.  But the Craft client knows it should never overwrite an existing `license.key` file, so it reports that error.

Solution: remove the existing `license.key` file (since it probably belongs to another site anyway) and let the web service generate a new one for you.

Comment: Ok, i try that. remove the key from local and staging and live. And what you mean with webservice? :) Sorry :/

Comment: No worries... the web service (elliott.craftcms.com) is the server on our end that all Craft client installations talk to for license verification, update checks, etc.

Comment: I've deleted the license.key on my local machine and checkt for updates but same message again. And he creates a new license.key file.

Here my hearty config:

$envs = array(
  'dev' => 'craft.xxx.dev',
  'stage' => 'staging.xxx.com',
  'prod' => 'xxx.com,www.xxx.com,live.xxx.com',
);

Comment: Haha OK. On my live site now it comes this:
You’re running Craft Pro with a Craft Personal license. Resolve ->

What I must do now? :/

Comment: Probably be better is we took this over to support@craftcms.com. Can you shoot an email there with the domain name of the live site?